# How to set sqlalchemy in Python when connect to postgresql's table with character ñ in columns

Tags: python, postgresql, encoding, pandas, sqlalchemy

Here is the code I am trying run:

```
import pandas as p
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

> Out[24]: 'Spanish_Argentina.1252'

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine    
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost/mdb',client_encoding = 'WIN1252')
p.read_sql("SELECT año FROM nacvivos.nac LIMIT 10",engine)
```

But a Had this encoding problem:

> ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) no existe la columna «aã±o»
>   LINE 1: SELECT aÃ±o FROM nacvivos.nac LIMIT 10
>                  ^
>    'SELECT a\xc3\xb1o FROM nacvivos.nac LIMIT 10' {}

How should I set configuration in python for deal with this? Ignoring the obvious answer that modify the name of the column will solve the problem.  Database in postgresql is win1252 encoding. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the `encoding` keyword in `create_engine` (and not `client_encoding`), with 'cp1252' being the python codec name for 'WIN1252':

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost/mdb', encoding='cp1252')
```

and then be sure your query is also encoded:

```
qry = u"SELECT año FROM nacvivos.nac LIMIT 10".encode('cp1252')
pd.read_sql(qry, engine)
```

With these two steps, I was able to read in a table with 'año' as a column name.